# undefined reference to '__objc_class_name_...'

Tags: objective-c, gnu-make, gnustep

I am building an executable (GNUstep).

It depends on a `libLibname.a` static lib.

In the GNUmakefile of the executable I am linking `libLibname.a` like this:

```
executableToolName_LDFLAGS = /usr/GNUstep/Local/Library/Libraries/libLibname.a
```

It claims to link without errors:

```
Linking tool executableToolName ...
```

Problem: It seems to not find the symbols:

```
main.m:29: error: undefined reference to '._OBJC_REF_CLASS_SomeClassNameOfLibLibname'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`..._LDFLAGS`is only for libray targets.

For tool targets, linked libs must be listed in `ADDITIONAL_OBJC_LIBS`, prefixed with `-l`